# For some reasons, my minidlna server is only accesible on localhost, and not visible on the network. Why could that be?

Tags: minidlna

I have tried to run minidlna, but I can't manage to access it from the network.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please remember to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark and up-arrow icons just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MiniDLNA uses UDP port 1900 & TCP port 8200. If using a firewall the the ssdp (1900/udp) and trivnet1 (8200/tcp) ports will need to be opened.

Also forward these ports in your router if you're trying to reach it from the outside (but be aware of the security implications).

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MiniDLNA

Comment: I'm not trying to reach it from outside, just in the local network. But it only works on the same computer somehow.

Comment: @sevku Did you open the ports in your firewall?

Comment:  yep, just remembered that I've been playing around with the firewall. It works now.

Comment: @sevku status please...